# How do I align multiple vertices between diagonal endppoints

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I frequently have several vertices requiring alignment between non-axis aligned endpoints. I know you can create a custom orientation, then scale to zero, but for a lot of separate instances, is there a script or an addon which has this as a command? It would go something like

1. select endpoints,
2. select vertices  between those endpoints,
3. Go.

I couldn't see how to do it in Mesh Align Plus & a few others.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen to the vertices between the endpoints? Each one goes to the nearest point on the line? Trying to visualize what's happening here. Can you provide a picture?